# TFS Build Server with solution in sub folder

Tags: tfs, msbuild

```
Visual Studio 2015
TFS 2012
```

I have a project where there are about 40 projects.  The layout is something like this.

```
*Proj 1
*Proj 2
*System -> System.SLN
*System -> Proj 3
*System -> Proj 4
```

All of the projects are in the solution but half of the projects are in a folder one up from the solution.

The issue is that the build server says that it cannot find the projects that are one folder up (Proj 1 and Proj 2).  Is there something I can do to get all of the projects to compile on the build server?

Comment: Try creating a solution beneath all of the projects (or as far down as possible) and see if that works. If so, you're golden.  Also, a real error message would help clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the workspace repository mappings in your build definition are setup where the root is at the solution, making the build unable to get the parent folder. Set the root mapping to its parent folder instead.

Your .sln also might be configured to work specifically on your machine instead of having relative paths. Make sure the references to each project use something like  `"..\proj 1"` instead of `"D:\work\proj 1"`.

I don't have enough info for a definitive answer; I am making **many** assumtions based on the limited info given.

Comment: In the build defintion:  Source settings was set to the sub folder.  I had to change that path and it saw all of the projects.